# Attach/Detach to a remote instance of Eclipse

Tags: linux, eclipse, xserver

When using Eclipse over X-Windows on a remote shell (X port forwarding), is there a way to simply detach my X connection and come back to the process later.  For a little more clarity, I'm on a Windows machine and have to reboot.  I'd like to keep Eclipse running and come back where I left off.  Eclipse is running on my Windows machine through an X-Server connected to a Linux box.

I'm thinking something like [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) could do the trick.  However, I do a Ctrl-Z to stop Eclipse and it won't close the Eclipse Window.  If I restart the X-Server in Windows, Eclipse fails when I try `fg 1`.  Any other options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have zero experience with it, but [xpra](http://code.google.com/p/partiwm/wiki/xpra) sounds like exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: That was the hint that I needed.  Xpra works great if you know how to use it.

Comment: the version in the link has not been updated in years, try [this fork](http://xpra.org/) instead

Answer (score 4):

Xpra did everything that I needed, but it was not clear exactly how it worked.  I was able to get it working by opening two PuTTY sessions in windows, one server and one client.  Also, the Google Code is out-dated.  Instead, install from http://xpra.devloop.org.uk/dists/xpra-0.0.7.9.tar.bz2.  I'm not sure how it's different, but it worked for me.  The README tells how to build the package.  It is necessary to apt-get a bunch of other stuff.  But, here are the missing pieces on how to get it work as I describe above:

Setup server:

```
cd ~/download/xpra/xpra-0.0.7.9
export PYTHONPATH=$PWD/install/lib/python:$PYTHONPATH
./install/bin/xpra start :10
export DISPLAY=:10
xterm&
```

Setup client:

```
cd ~/download/xpra/xpra-0.0.7.9
export PYTHONPATH=$PWD/install/lib/python:$PYTHONPATH
./install/bin/xpra attach :10
```

Notes:

- The Windows xpra installer is not needed for this configuration.  I don't know what it's supposed to do.
- Be sure to run Xming on Windows.
- Be sure to enable X port forwarding on the client PuTTY window.
- Launch whatever you want from the xterm window. (ie Eclipse)
- You can close the server window once xterm is up.
- Hit ctrl-c in the client window to detach from the session.
- Do all the client commands again to re-attach..even after restarting PuTTY, the Xming, or Windows itself.

Comment: Unless your windows installation has all the required bits (python/gtk/pygtk/python-imaging/... cygwin, and many other bits) this will not work. That is why there is a Windows installer which includes everything that you need. You do not need Xming at all unless you use a cygwin type of environment: modern versions of pygtk on MS Windows run natively.